# .zip made on Mac OS, .jpg files with weird characters on Windows

Tags: windows-7, macos, zip, encoding

I received a zip file from a Mac OS user with several hundred of .jpg files, some with very long names. Opening the .zip file wit 7-zip on my Win 7 machine, lots of these files have very weird characters; I guess they were encoded like this in the zipping  process. Here is a sample

```
Õìüþ½╣µûÄþ¼║Þ░▒ .jpg
```

Some files have more legible names like

```
Histoire dÔÇÖO.jpg
```

Wich should be `Histoire d'O.jpg` so I can guess that `ÔÇÖ` is a weird encoding for the single quote `'` character, I can see this matching in many other files aswell.

Should I tell him to send them again in some other format? Is there a way to open these files on my machine with correct names?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a sort of "work around". 
Since the Host OS creating the zip file is a Mac I tried uploading this .zip on a Linux web server I manage, then I unpacked the zip, and the files were correctly named once extracted. 
So I repacked the files in zip and downloaded on my machine, now all files have the correct names.

I'll just leave this here as a quick memorandum, I hope there are are other solutions more practical than this!